# How to make hooks (afterStep) to run and finish before next step is executed?

Tags: node.js, cucumber, hook, webdriver-io

Using wdio v4 + cucumber i used some afterSteps and know im trying to use the same in v5 + cucumber but it seems not to be running in order.
On my afterStep i have certain validations, i.e. if result.status === failed then i take a screenshot and do some extra steps, the problem is i am able to take the screenshot but im never able to do the extra steps because when the afterStep is executed, the runner is already executing another test case.

Sometimes it successfully takes the screenshot of the page with the error, but the other steps are never completed since when it gets there, the runner is already executing another test case..

This is the code im using on my afterStep for the v5 (updated from v4):

```
afterStep: function (uri, feature, scenario, step, result) {
        if (result.status === 'failed') {
            const path =  './errorShots/'+Date.now()+'.png';
            browser.saveScreenshot(path);
            const allitems = $('.slds-icon-waffle');
            const logoutBut = $('button[title="Logout"]');
            const adminMenu = $('.oneAppLauncherItemList a[title="Parsable Admin"]');
            const sfProfilelogo = $('.profileTrigger');
            const sflogOut = $('.profile-link-label.logout.uiOutputURL');
            this.allitems.waitForDisplayed();
            this.allitems.click();
            this.adminMenu.waitForVisible();
            this.adminMenu.click();
            browser.pause(2000)
            if (this.logoutBut.isVisible()) {   
                this.logoutBut.click();
            }
            this.sfProfilelogo.waitForVisible();
            this.sfProfilelogo.click();
            this.sflogOut.waitForVisible();
            this.sflogOut.click();
        } 
        console.log(step.text + ' is ' + result.status)
    },
```

**WebdriverIO version: v5.11.2
**Mode:Selenium Standalone
**If WDIO Testrunner, running sync/async: sync
**Node.js version: v10.16.0
**NPM version: v6.9.0
**Browser name and version: Chrome
**Platform name and version: MacOS

How can i ensure the afterStep is completely executed before the next step is executed?
I have tried using promises but im not sure if i was implementing well, any help?

Comment: Not sure with the node.js implementation, but generally you have to handle the screenshot and steps in the `after` (after scenario) not after step. Does the `scenario` continue once the step is failed or does it move onto the next scenario. If the it's moving on to the next scenario then make sure to use `after` hook.

Answer (score 0):

There was an existing issue with v4 (with cucumber) related to hooks (not sure that got fixed).

Ref: https://github.com/webdriverio-boneyard/wdio-cucumber-framework/issues/151

We did the following in our project as a workaround to overcome it: Add the below code as part of the stepDefinition file.

```
// Added this hook to make failed step screenshot feature work.
// NOTE: Since the after hook is placed here there cannot be AFTER hooks in runner file.
After((scenario)=>{
    if(Status.FAILED === scenario.result.status){
        browser.screenshot();
        console.log('Scenario Failed. Screenshot taken!!');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i managed to make it work using the cucumber hooks as you mentioned instead of the ones on the wdio config file.
This is still an issue on the hooks for the wdio v5 + cucumber.
https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/4207

Comment: Hi Jorge, Good that we have the ticket to follow up. We do not prefer to migrate to v5 because it is just released :P we will wait till people experiment with it.. :)